# How to change some columns name when using pd.read_excel

Tags: pandas, excel

When importing `xlsx` using `pd.read_excel()`,
how to change column name partially?

For example,
Excel `data.xlsx`  consists 99 columns like `col_1`, `col_1`, `col_3` .... `col_99`.

I'd like to only `rename = {'col_1' : 'ID', 'col_2' : 'name', 'col_3' : 'score'}`

As for other columns `col_4` ~ `col_99`, no need to rename.

`pd.read_excel('data.xlsx')` has option `names = []`, but it need whole columns change.

Is there any other way to change some of columns, when using `pd.read_excel()`?v

Comment: Is there an interest in doing this while reading the file, compared to right after as a usual dataframe operation?

Comment: I don't like it when statements are folded into several lines. Unwind as much as possible in one line. It's a matter of personal preference. No special reasons.

Comment: I don't think you can do it in read_excel. but you can call the rename command after read_excel e.g. df = pd.read_excel("book1.xlsx").rename(columns=rename) where rename is your dictionary